# Cut Function With Levels of Factor Variable in R

Tags: r

I have a simple data frame with two variables, RowID and Country:

```
RowID    Country
1         USA
2         Spain
3         USA
4         USA
5         Spain
6         Spain
```

I am able to use the cut function to create bins for the full data using

```
df$Bin<-cut(df$RowID,breaks=3)
```

Which produces:

```
RowID   Country    Bin
1         USA      1
2         Spain    1
3         USA      2
4         USA      2
5         Spain    3    
6         Spain    3
```

However, is it possible to apply the cut function within each level of the variable Country?
In other words, ending up with:

```
RowID   Country    Bin
1         USA      1
2         Spain    1
3         USA      2
4         USA      3
5         Spain    2    
6         Spain    3
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do the following using dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Country)          %>%
  mutate(Bin = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup
```

Output

```
##Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
##
##  RowID Country   Bin
##  (int)   (chr) (int)
##1     1     USA     1
##2     2   Spain     1
##3     3     USA     2
##4     4     USA     3
##5     5   Spain     2
##6     6   Spain     3
```

**EDIT**

For the question that came up in a comment, about how to break each country up into bins (e.g. if there are 100 rows for a country that you want to break up into 10 bins), the following code can be used

```
break_count <- 2
df3 %>%
  group_by(Country)                            %>%
  mutate(Bin = cut(row_number(), break_count)) %>%
  ungroup
```

A `break_count` of 2 was used above but can be changed.  Only the `mutate` line is different from the first variation of the solution.

Comment: Thanks for your response!  It looks like this method works great for counting the number of rows within each country, but is it possible to use this approach with the binning functionality of "cut."  For example, if there are 100 rows within each country, creating 10 bins?

Comment: You may be able to do that by replacing the `mutate(Bin = row_number())` with `mutate(Bin = cut(row_number(), 2))` (of course replacing `2` with the number of desired bins).

Comment: @hooplaer23, if the modification in the previous comment works for you on a bigger data set, I can add the example to the answer. Just replacing the call to `mutate` should be all that is needed.

Comment: I tried this edit on the bigger data set and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `ave`

```
 df$Bin <- with(df, ave(RowID, Country, FUN=seq_along))
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun, this definitely works for the example I have given, but it looks like it is limited to essentially creating one bin for each observation within each level of country.  I was hoping to find a solution where I could for instance have 10 bins across 100 observations within each level of country, which I was trying to use the "cut" function.

Comment: @hooplaer23 My previous solution (before the edit) was using `cut`, but it gives a different set of values when compared to the expected output you wanted. i.e. `with(df, ave(RowID, Country, FUN=function(x) cut(x, breaks=3)))`